useState set method not changing my state - react native
I'm working on a part of an application dealing with a deck of cards. For however many cards a player is supposed to have, I am looping through a deck of cards held in a state, randomly picking a card, assigning it to that player and then removing it from the deck. This all works correctly but when the deck is empty (.length === 0), I want to invoke a shuffle() method that will set the deck equal to the discard pile which is also an array held in a useState. The discard pile is also working as expected but for some reason when trying to set the currentDeck to the discard pile, using setCurrentDeck(discardPile), the currentDeck array remains empty. (I've also tried setCurrentDeck([...discardPile])).
I know this mostly likely has to do with how React handles batching hook calls, and that the value of currentDeck is not what I think it is because of the other setCurrentDeck() calls, but I'm still not able to figure out what's going on.
My code (simplified):
const [currentDeck, setCurrentDeck] = useState(deck) // 'deck' is a hard coded array of cards
const [discardPile, setDiscardPile] = useState([])
const [faceUpCard, setFaceUpCard] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentDeck.length === 0) {
      const temp = discardPile;
      setCurrentDeck([...temp]);
      setDiscardPile([]);
    }
  }, [currentDeck]);

  function deal() {
    if (readyToDeal) {
      for (let i = 0; i < round + 2; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < players.length; j++) {
          const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentDeck.length);
          // players are assigned cards
          currentDeck.splice(rand, 1); // card that was assigned is removed from deck
          setCurrentDeck([...currentDeck]);
        }
      }
      const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentDeck.length);
      setFaceUpCard(currentDeck[rand]);
      currentDeck.splice(rand, 1);
      setCurrentDeck([...currentDeck]);
      setReadyToDeal(false);
    }
  }

I have also tried setting currentDeck with a shuffle method like this:

  function shuffle() {
    const temp = discardPile;
    setCurrentDeck([ ...temp]);
    setDiscardPile([]);
  }

  function deal() {
    if (readyToDeal) {
      for (let i = 0; i < round + 2; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < players.length; j++) {
          if (currentDeck.length === 0) {
            shuffle();
          }
          const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentDeck.length);
          // players are assigned cards
          currentDeck.splice(rand, 1); // card that was assigned is removed from deck
          setCurrentDeck([...currentDeck]);
        }
      }
      const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentDeck.length);
      setFaceUpCard(currentDeck[rand]);
      currentDeck.splice(rand, 1);
      setCurrentDeck([...currentDeck]);
      setReadyToDeal(false);
    }
  }

but still no luck. Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Try with this instead of what you have but yeah definitely has something to do with the fact that you are updating the state with the same object modified instead of passing a new one:
const temp = [...discardPile];
setCurrentDeck(temp);

@IbrahimCS tried this but still didn't work, thank you though. Do you think I need to not be calling 'setCurrentDeck(}' multiple times in the same function?

You need to understand how useEffect and state is supposed to be used in React.

You should not rely on when or how often useEffect is executed. You should only use it to declare which state depends on which other state (see also "You Might Not Need an Effect").

The "state" from setState (the value and the set... function) should be used to e.g. update based on some other state or on user actions. It should not be used like a normal "variable".



When you call useState, you are telling React that you want this component to remember something

Note that the complete for loop runs until it is finished before React even tries to execute setCurrentDeck. When the for loop is finished, all set... functions are executed, which is effectively like only the last one was executed.
Maybe a solution:
I suppose you probably should build the new deck using "normal" javascript patterns (maybe in a separate function), i.e. without using React specific patterns. Then, when the deck is created and it's time to interact with the user and update the screen again, update the React state with the ready built deck.

Thank you! This makes total sense, I was able to get it working. I got a little hook crazy and started writing them without thinking about what it is I actually needed them to do. I appreciate the advice

Happy it helped! Yes, sometimes we just need somebody to tell us the obvious, because we don't trust ourselves :)
